# Isomorphic semidirect products?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $N\rtimes_\varphi H$ and $N\rtimes_\psi H$ be semidirect products such that $\psi$, for $h\in H$, is given by the formula
$$
\psi(h)=\sigma\circ\varphi(h)\circ\sigma^{-1}
$$
for some $\sigma\in\text{Aut}(N)$.

Is it true that
$$
N\rtimes_\psi H\cong N\rtimes_\varphi H?
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a function
$$\alpha :N\rtimes_\varphi H\to N\rtimes_\psi H:(n,h)\mapsto (\sigma (n),h).$$
You can easily check, using the fact that $\sigma\in Aut(N)$ and that $\sigma \circ \varphi(h)=\psi(h)\circ \sigma$ for all $h\in H$, that this is a group homomorphism. By a similar reasoning,
$$\beta:N\rtimes_\psi H\to N\rtimes_\varphi H:(n,h)\mapsto (\sigma^{-1}(n),h)$$
is a group homomorphism, and it is easily seen to be an inverse for $\alpha$, which is thus an isomorphism.